# Ruby on Rails find all parents with child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models - Topic and ContentItems.

A topic has_many content_items but a topic can be created without any pre-existing content_items.

Does anyone know how I can select all Topics with at least one content_item without using a counter cache?

currently I'm doing something like:

```
Topic.joins(:content_items).uniq
```

but that handles it in memory so if I can't chain a limit or order off of it i.e. I can't do

```
Topic.joins(:content_items).uniq.limit(10).order("created_at DESC")
```

Counter cache is a possible long term option but it's a bit larger of a change than I'd like to make right now unless there are no better solutions.

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
Topic.joins(:content_items).select("DISTINCT topics.*")
```

OR

```
Topic.include(:content_items).where("content_items.id IS NULL")
```

Comment: There was a typo in the 2nd solution. I have fixed it.